# Application leads to memory leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, tomcat7, smartgwt, heap-memory

Currently working in smartGWT  project where it consumes a lot of memory when the application performs any CRUD or Grid loading and refreshing operations and  the application deployed in tomcat server 7.0 . I have tried thread specification and Memory restriction in tomcat but it won't works.Could you please suggest way to avoid memory leak. awaiting for your reply.

Comment: Accept the below answer if you get adequate information so that this question will not show in unanswered section.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid memory leak. We should get information on the objects allocated on the application. If you are using IBM JDK then JVM will collect javacore, system core and snaptrace  when JVM throws OutOfMemory. Until System throws OOM we will not get clear picture on  object allocation and de allocation pattern.

For Example: if you take systemcore in middle of the application run time. There are possibilities that GC yet to run to clean dead objects so  the current snapshot may not give the full picture of the application allocation.
When JVM throws OOM it means GC kicked on  and all possible collection of dead objects are taken care so  analyzing the  existing objects in the heap will  reflect the true information on the java heap.

Once you collect logs load the system core in Memory Analyzer tool.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/tools/memoryanalyzer/
It will help you in identifying leaks.

If you using Oracle JDK please follow 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html